# JPA merge on auto increment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity that has the following multiple fields along with a field that is autogenerated on an insert

Now everytime I want to do an update using merge() in my DAO, it will add a new entry instead of updating the current entry. I am assuming this is due to UPDATE statement on id and the id is new everytime. Is there a way within JPA (Hibernate) to avoid writing a new record in the database and just to an update instead. Please find below my entity object:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "CONFIG_ID")
private long configID;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "CID", referencedColumnName = "CID", insertable = true, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "DID", referencedColumnName = "DID", insertable = true, updatable = false)})
@Version private <Object> dE;
@Column(name = "HISTORY", nullable = false, unique = false)
private String history;
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge()` is supposed for detached entity use . It is an update or insert action depending if the identity of the merged object is null or not. If it is null , a new record will be inserted.

To correctly update an entity in JPA , you simply load it and change its properties. When the transaction commit , JPA will figure out if there are any properties changes and issue the UPDATE SQL if there are changes. No need to call any methods on `EntityManager` for any update.

Reference:

- [JPA wiki - Merge](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Merge)